# My webpage is only showing one line per line on a mobile phone device

Tags: wordpress

I have created a webpage that displays correctly on a desktop and tablet. However, it only displays one letter per line on a mobile phone. Here is my [webpage](https://www.obrienrealestate.com.au/off-market-real-estate/)

Comment: Can you supply a screenshot. Looks fine on my end.

Comment: It looks perfect on a desktop or laptop. But it is not displaying correctly on a mobile phone.

Comment: Hi Fongool. Many different mobile phones exist with different mobile browsers (and then there are emulators which not always yield correct results). So some people might not experience any visual problems on their specific mobile browser, while others might on their. Please provide a screenshot and which mobile browser/browsers you use. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for replying again Tokant. I must be stupid because i dont know how to add a screenshot here. So, if you look at the web page on a mobile you will see what i mean. I use a Samsung Android. But, if i use the "inspect" option on a variety of mobile phones i get the same result  www.obrienrealestate.com.au/off-market-real-estate

Comment: Hi Tokant, I worked it out. It was to do with the left and right margins i had set up for the columns. I had them at 200px. When i reduced them to 10 px the pages appear correctly on the mobile devices. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: You're welcome :-)